# Simplifying a drop down form input for date: day month year <html>

Tags: php, html, forms, html-select

There are 29+ days in a month, I am creating a form using select and option.  But this means I will need 31 options for day, 12 for month and a bunch more for the year.

Is there a better way to do it?  I'm not looking for plug-ins, I am trying to make some tidy code to replace some old and messy code.  Can I use a PHP for loop? And how would I go about doing this?  What would it look like (in terms of mixing up the PHP and HTML variables and functions)?

Comment: dropdowns just to pick a number are horrible user interfaces. use a plain text field and then put in some range enforcement in the verfication/validation code.

Comment: Marc is correct. You should follow the idea.

Comment: so just make a constraint that automatically makes anything above 'MaxDaysInMonth' become 'MaxDaysInMonth' and a similar constraint for less than 1?  Also, thank you Marcelo for the method to find the days in current month.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the best way to do this, but is what your asking.
Look:

```php
<select name="d">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
    <?php endfor ?>
</select>

<select name="m">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
    <?php endfor ?>
</select>
```

and if you need to take the number of the days in the current/specific month use

```php
$current_month = date('m');
$number_of_day_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $current_month , date('Y'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML5, then create an `<input type="date">`. 
Safari, Opera and Chrome already do support this input type. In browsers with no date-input-support, such an input degrades to a simple text field.

- The specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html
- Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

You MUST implement validation on server-side (in PHP in your case) anyway - so text field is not a tragedy. You may also use *simple* JavaScript to validate user input before submitting the form data as well.

If you want nice calendar widget in all (A-grade-)browsers, you'll *need* to use a plugin or implement this yourself in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, but in the old browsers? If he dont want use javascripts, so do it with PHP is the best way.

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho: but *how* can you do it without JavaScript? Use case: I select "January" and have 31 options available. Then, I select "February" (without submitting the form!) and the number of options must become 28 or 29, i.e. my HTML must change dynamically. Without JavaScript, I would have to submit the form every time I select another month (or year if current month is February), so that PHP can re-generate HTML...

Comment: Yes, of course, for this really is impossible without javascript. By the way, if need of javascript, the best is use jQuery UI datepicker or other framework UI, to dont have the throuble to make a fallback to HTML5 input[date]

Answer (score -2):

If your trying to simply use HTML (no plugin), this should get you started:

```
<select name="Month">
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="February">February</option>
  <option selected value="March">March</option>
</select>
<select name="Day">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option selected value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="Year">
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option selected value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dbpj/)

But I would recommend a JavaScript solution, like jQuery's datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: Voted down due to ignoring what he was asking. He asked for something DYNAMIC, since each month has a different amount of days in it.